# Do I need to include confounding variables in my regression model when I use instrument variables?

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables

Suppose I believe 'Age', 'Gender', 'Ability', and 'Motivation' are confounding variables influencing both the dependent variable and endogenous variables. I use the 'Education Level' for the treatment variable and 'Income' for the dependent variable. Having been through many open examples on this topic, most of them use the instrument variable 'Distance' only. So I started wondering if I can use the instrument variable 'Distance' to solve endogeneity problem without considering confounding variables as covariates.

Do I need or should include confounding variables as covariates in my regression model?

Answer (score 9):

The point of an instrumental variable (IV) is that it works even when the confounding variables are unknown. If they are all known, I'm not sure it makes sense to use an IV approach. In any case, if you are using the instrument, you would be using something like [2SLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation#Interpretation_as_two-stage_least_squares), and not a conventional regression with the covariates.

Comment: So I can include some confounding variables as covariates if I have and build the model using 2SLS?

Comment: If your instrument is valid, you don't need to worry about confounding when using 2SLS by definition. However, if you know all covariates, you wouldn't need an IV approach in the first place since you can just run a regression with control variables. If you have an IV and know all covariates, it might be an idea to compare the IV results to the conventional regression with control covariates.

Comment: Well, you use the IVs to solve the endogeneity issues around (here) education. If there are further regressors (here, argued to be gender etc.) that are relevant to the causal question at hand (in the sense of being related to the regressor of interest - education - and the dep. variable) they need to be included as well - otherwise, you would reintroduce an omitted variable bias. If you actually do observe ability though, then the typical story for why education is endogenous when omitting ability does not apply anymore, so that an IV approach may not be necessary.

Comment: So far I've been stating the general idea of IV vs. regression control, but if there is still an open question perhaps a question edit including a DAG to formalize the dependencies would be a good idea to see if there is something specific about this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I second that - this is likely to help clarify what and how needs to be controlled for.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to include the covariates if they are confounders for the effect of *the instrument* on the outcome**. Consider the following causal diagrams (aka DAGs)

[image: two DAGs]

In both scenarios, one option to estimate the effect of the treatment $(D)$ on the outcome $(Y)$ is to include $X_1$ and $X_2$ as covariates, assuming they are observable. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are unobserved, you can instead use $Z$ as an instrument for $D$ in Scenario 1. In Scenario 2, however, you would have to include $X_1$ as a covariate for $Z$ to be a valid instrument.

Here's an example using Card's ''college proximity'' data, where we are trying to estimate the effect of education on earnings using `nearc4` (a dummy, = 1 if the individual grew up close to a 4-year college) as an instrument for years of education.

```
library(wooldridge)
library(ivreg)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

data("card")
card <- card[!is.na(card$IQ),]

fs0 <- lm(educ ~ nearc4, data = card)
coeftest(fs0, vcov. = vcovHC, type = "HC1")

t test of coefficients:

             Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 13.590682   0.088891 152.8913 < 2.2e-16 ***
nearc4       0.468222   0.107339   4.3621 1.352e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

College proximity is associated with about half a year more of schooling and can be used as an instrument if it is as good as randomly assigned, meaning that people who grew up close to a college and far from a college should be comparable in all other respects. However, if we check for balance in IQ

```
bal <- lm(IQ ~ nearc4, data = card)
coeftest(bal, vcov. = vcovHC, type = "HC1")

t test of coefficients:

             Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 100.61065    0.63311 158.9162 < 2.2e-16 ***
nearc4        2.59620    0.74945   3.4641 0.0005428 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

we find that people who grew up close to a college have a higher IQ on average. I'm not sure when the IQ-test was actually administered, but let's assume that everyone took it on the first year of high schoool, which would mean that the IQ difference cannot be due to a difference in how many years of schooling were completed. Rather, college proximity appears not to be as-if randomly assigned.

If we are sure that IQ is **the only** characteristic in which people who grow up close to / fram from a college differ, we could adjust for it to make the instrument valid.

```
iv1 <- ivreg(log(wage) ~ educ + IQ | nearc4 + IQ, data = card)
coeftest(iv1, vcov. = vcovHC, type = "HC1")

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.6734020  0.8148133  4.5083 6.903e-06 ***
educ         0.3332829  0.1290477  2.5826  0.009873 ** 
IQ          -0.0193081  0.0097107 -1.9883  0.046909 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If there are more confounders for the effect of college proximity on earnings, we must include them as covariates as well.